# Selenium automation clicking next button isnt responding

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the next button in the form on this webpage

https://www.salesforce.com/uk/form/signup/freetrial-sales-pe/?d=cta-jumbotron-2-freetrial

but I am getting an error that no such element: Unable to locate element:

below is the XPath that I used. I could fill in all the other fields in the form, just the next button.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"signup_form_UAvC\"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause of the issue:** Your below XPath expression is not correct. The reason it is not correct is because the `id` attribute's value is dynamic. So in the following, `id=signup_form_UAvC`, value `UAvC` keeps changing every time you load the page.

```
//*[@id=\"signup_form_UAvC\"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]
```

**Solution:** Use below XPath expression instead, which is more user readable:

```
//span[text()='Next']
```

Assuming this is the button you want to click:

[image]

**Check the code below:**

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.salesforce.com/uk/form/signup/freetrial-sales-pe/?d=cta-jumbotron-2-freetrial");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
// Click on Accept Cookie button
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']"))).click(); 
        
// Click on Next button
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Before clicking any web element we need to use waiting condition 

WebDriver driver=driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//inspect the web element of next button
WebElement nextButton=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']"));
nextButton.click();
```